# Why does AIR badge always say 'install' when I have already installed the AIR application?

Tags: air, installation, digital-certificate, sign

I have developed an Adobe AIR application which users install and launch from my web page. I use the install badge to install the AIR app if it is not already installed on the users computer. Before I had the app signed this install only happened if the AIR app was not already installed, once it had been installed the AIR app would be launched from the install badge rather than being installed again.

Since digitally signing the AIR app with my thawte signature the AIR badge keeps trying to install it even if it already exists and I get the message "The same version of the application you opened already exists on this system. Would you like to run the version already installed?"

It seems that the badge is not detecting the already installed version.

Have I missed a step when i published the signed version ( i realise that technically i always had a signed version it was just a self-signed version ) maybe I need to update the badge with the new signature or something?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using Adobe AIR version 1.5 and my new certificate generated a new publisher ID which I had to update in my badge.swf. Once I had added the new publisher Id to the badge.swf the install only happened once then subsequent clicks on the badge would launch the app as expected.